# How to find the required id in json

Tags: python, json

I have json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1116,
        "en_name": "Location, Surroundings",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 819,
                "en_name": "Location Satisfaction",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1004,
                "en_name": "Car Parking Facilities",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 1297,
                        "en_name": "Availability and general perception of parking",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1123,
                "en_name": "On the road ",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to find the id and get the name.
For example, if I ask the algorithm to find a name by ID 1297, then it should give
me "Accessibility and general perception of parking".

The algorithm should run through the entire array of the dictionary and also run through all "children", which may also contain "children"

```
while True:
            for data in self.main_taxonomy:
                while len(data["children"]) != 0:
                    if data["id"] == id:
                        return data["name"]
                    else:
                        data = data["children"]
```

I tried to do it this way, but it didn't check all the nesting.

Comment: Hi. Wrap your sample code in a function.  Add a recursive call to the same function if the type of element you are inspecting is a `list`. Be careful to pass the list as the new argument of that function.

 Keep in mind that whenever you come across "and also run through all 'children', which may also contain 'children'" this means you're looking at a recursive solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a recursive function like this:

```py
def recursive_find(id_, children):
    for child in children:
        if child.get('id')==id_:
            return child['en_name']
        res = recursive_find(id,child.get('children',[])
        if res:
            return res
    return None
```

This function will return a `en_name` property if `id` matches else returns `None`, call it on main `array` of your json like `recursive_find(<your_id_here>, data)`

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved as a recursive function:

- Loop over the entries.
- Your base case, check if the entry has the ID you are looking for
- Else, if the entry has children, check if any of them have the ID
- Else, return None.

```
def find_element_by_id(entries, ID):
    for entry in entries:
        if entry["id"] == ID:
            return entry["en_name"]
        if entry["children"]:
            rtn = find_element_by_id(entry["children"], ID)
            if rtn:
                return rtn
    return None
```

Example use:

```
data = [
    {
        "id": 1116,
        "en_name": "Location, Surroundings",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 819,
                "en_name": "Location Satisfaction",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 1004,
                "en_name": "Car Parking Facilities",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 1297,
                        "en_name": "Availability and general perception of parking",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1123,
                "en_name": "On the road ",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]

ret1 = find_element_by_id(data, 1297)
print(ret1)
```

Output:

```
Availability and general perception of parking
```